# Setting column height to 100% with foundation 6

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

So Im working on this Foundation 6 project, Ive hit a wall, and its frustrating the ever loving piss out of me.  Essentially what I am trying to do is ensure that my minimal content stays full screen.  I was trying to make sure that I was thinking mobile first, and so I kept my layout super simple, yet once my screen width gets below about 900px the images keep scaling leaving me with a ton of white space at the bottom between the images and the footer. Also the left image starts sliding to the left for some reason, but I figure if I can get it to keep its height it shouldn't be an issue.

Ive tried foundations equalizer, Ive played with a thousand variations of min-height and positioning, Ive enclosed it in container divs, but I just cant get the thing to work. Please help!

Heres the [link](http://spearzolutions.com)

Thanks in advance!  Id really rather not do a thousand media queries

Answer (score 0):

For the css...

```
.container {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.column, .columns {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The reason your img flies away to the left is based on `rem` measurements.  [This](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/) is a bit of a heavy read, but it seems to give a better understanding on how `rem` works.  I've never really used them, so I can't offer more help there.

Also, your site was awfully slow to load.  It has a 3.5mb file and that is a huge load for a single image, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think I may have have misrepresented the question.  I need the columns to take up the entire viewport height so that there is no negative space.  While your fix did pull the footer up, it didnt accomplish that for me.  And as far as the img goes I know, Im going to compress it once I figure this out

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out.  I was attacking the picture frame instead of the picture.  Once that thought crossed my mind I was able to set the images in vh instead of regular percentages and it worked like a charm.  Not sure why we even use percentages, pixels, em's anymore since we have that but I will avoid it like the plague from now on!